# Flux not compiling with React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Flux is not working with react 18.
Error is:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.2 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from flux@4.0.3
```

What is the official strategy to resolve this error?

Comment: _"[The Flux library is no longer being updated](https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/563#issuecomment-1126833480) and we don't have intentions to make Flux compatible with React 18 as we're still using some UNSAFE lifecycle APIs. [It's better to just migrate to another store instead if you want to upgrade to React 18.](https://github.com/facebook/flux#%EF%B8%8F-the-flux-project-is-in-maintenance-mode-and-there-are-many-more-sophisticated-alternatives-available-eg-redux-mobx-or-recoil-and-we-would-recommend-using-them-instead)"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Flux** library is no longer being updated and not compatible with **React 18** .
just  migrate to another store instead or downgrade react version.

there are many more sophisticated alternatives available (e.g. `Redux`...)
check it in the [flux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flux) library

Answer (score 0):

use `npm install flux  --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: You might want to give some context to your answer. What is this command doing? How is this helping solving the issue?